# Apache POI - No external workbook with name

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I tried to add a workbook, which is accessable online, to an excel file using the above mentioned library. 
However, I receive the following exception: "No external workbook with name ..."

I do not care if Apache POI can find the external workbook, as I know for sure it exists at that location. If I add it manually, it works.

My question is, can I remove this exception or diable the validation? I simply want to add the URL as a formular in excel.
Plain text is not working sadly.

Thank you for your help!

Here the complete Stacktrace (Please do not suggest removing the G in front of HTTP, as I have tried this and it is not working):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No external workbook with name 'Ghttp://my-test-homepage.de/download/test.xls'
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.LinkTable.getExternalSheetIndex(LinkTable.java:445)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.getExternalSheetIndex(InternalWorkbook.java:1594)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getSheetExtIx(HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:291)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.get3DReferencePtg(HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:88)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.createAreaRefParseNode(FormulaParser.java:975)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:579)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:322)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1540)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1498)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1485)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1858)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1986)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1970)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1927)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.intersectionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1900)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1880)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:2028)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:190)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.HSSFFormulaParser.parse(HSSFFormulaParser.java:79)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellFormula(HSSFCell.java:621)
    at test.app.main.ApplicationStarter.main(ApplicationStarter.java:53)
```

Here is the complete source code:

```
private static final String PATH_TO_XLS_FILE = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/folder/value.xls";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    Workbook workbook = null;

    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(PATH_TO_XLS_FILE));
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Daten");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row currectRow = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currectRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell currectCell = cellIterator.next();
                if (currectCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA
                        && currectCell.getCellFormula().contains("key")) {
                    String link = "'[Ghttp://my-test-url.de/download/test.xls]value'!F4";
                    currectCell.setCellFormula(link);
                    }
                }
            }

            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(PATH_TO_XLS_FILE));
            workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileInputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileOutputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(workbook);
    }
}
```

I've tried to solve the problem by myself and now I can add the external link to the Excel workbook. Unfortunatelly, I got another problem. When I open the Excel file the external link cannot be resolved because a special sign is inserted by Apache POI. If I delete this special sign the external link can be resolved. So my new question is, how can I avoid that Apache POI add this special sign? Is it maybe an encoding problem? thank you for helping me!

Here my new source code:

```
private static void modifyExcelFile(String pathToXLS) {
    FileInputStream fileInputStreamLocal = null;
    InputStream inputStreamRemote = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    HSSFWorkbook workbookLocal = null;
    HSSFWorkbook workbookRemote = null;

    try {
        LOGGER.debug(LOGGER_START);
        fileInputStreamLocal = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToXLS));
        inputStreamRemote = new URL(URL_TO_DATA_FILE + FILE_NAME).openStream();
        workbookLocal = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStreamLocal);
        workbookRemote = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStreamRemote);

        workbookLocal.linkExternalWorkbook(URL_TO_DATA_FILE + FILE_NAME, workbookRemote);

        Sheet sheet = workbookLocal.getSheet(SHEET_NAME);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row currectRow = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currectRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell currectCell = cellIterator.next();
                if (currectCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA
                        && currectCell.getCellFormula().contains(FILE_NAME)) {
                    String suffix = currectCell.getCellFormula();
                    int positionOfBracket = suffix.indexOf("]");

                    if (positionOfBracket < 0) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    suffix = suffix.substring(positionOfBracket + 1, suffix.length());
                    String[] suffixes = null;
                    suffixes = suffix.split("'!");

                    if (suffixes.length != 2) {
                        suffixes = suffix.split("!");
                        if (suffixes.length != 2) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    String link = "'[" + URL_TO_DATA_FILE + FILE_NAME + "]" + suffixes[0] + "'!" + suffixes[1];
                    currectCell.setCellFormula(link);
                }
            }
        }

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToXLS));
        workbookLocal.write(fileOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        LOGGER.debug(LOGGER_ABORT);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileInputStreamLocal);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStreamRemote);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileOutputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(workbookLocal);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(workbookRemote);
        LOGGER.debug(LOGGER_END);
    }
}
```

and here a screenshot of the special sign added by Apache POI:
[special sign is inside the red area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifCxt.png)

Comment: Can I have the question in my mother tongue **Hindi**? I don't understand this language

Comment: Please post your questions in english only. I will translate for now, but you will also only receive questions in english.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't write my question in english and thank you very much to Sirence for translating!!

Comment: @AxelRichter I tried your suggestion but I get the same exception.

Comment: I added the URL manually to the Excel file with Excel and read it with Apache POI. The formula which is saved in this cell looks like `'[Ghttp://my-test-url.de/download/test.xls]value'!F2` So I think I must add the G in front of http and I have to add the whole URL into the brackets.

Comment: After I added the url once manually I can add the url via the application successfully. The problem is, I cannot add the url to each file once manually.... has anybody another idea for this??

Comment: The Excel is running on Windows and the document is uploaded on a Debian server on the internet. And the file name is test.xls the path before is an online location. For the online location the signs are valid.